# Run powershell commands in C#

Tags: sharepoint, powershell

```
RunspaceConfiguration psConfig = RunspaceConfiguration.Create();
Runspace psRunspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(psConfig);
psRunspace.Open();
using (Pipeline psPipeline = psRunspace.CreatePipeline())
            {

            // Define the command to be executed in this pipeline
            Command command = new Command("Add-spsolution");

            // Add a parameter to this command
            command.Parameters.Add("literalpath", @"c:\project3.wsp");

            // Add this command to the pipeline 
            psPipeline.Commands.Add(command);


                // Invoke the cmdlet
            try
            {
                Collection<PSObject> results = psPipeline.Invoke();
                Label1.Text = "hi"+results.ToString();
                // Process the results
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                Label1.Text = exception.ToString();// Process the exception here
            }

        }
```

It is throwing the exception:

```
System.Management.Automation.CommandNotFoundException: The term 'add-spsolution' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
```

Any suggestions why?

Comment: did you find any solution?

Answer (score 11):

Add this command first:

`Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell -EA 0`

Answer (score 8):

You must use the import-module command to load the correct module for sharepoint. Use get-module to find available modules.

To do this programmatically, see my post on the subject:

http://www.nivot.org/2010/05/03/PowerShell20DeveloperEssentials1InitializingARunspaceWithAModule.aspx

-Oisin

Answer (score 2):

I have this issue recently. In my case I was neither able to see the added solution nor able to add solution. So first I remove solution using below PowerShell Command:

```
(Get-SPSolution -Identity "YourSolution.wsp").Delete()
```

Then I was able to add my new code solution.

Answer (score -1):

Also make sure you are runing "Add-SPSolution" command from Web Applications, which is running on IIS,  and NOT with standard Visual Studio server (when you press F5).